# simple shell program unix file redirection for non built-in commands

Tags: c, linux, shell, unix, redirect

I am trying to write a simple shell program and am having problems with file redirection for non built-in commands. For example ./a.out < infile > outfile, would have the user complied program a.out take input from infile and output its output to outfile instead of the streams that it normally uses. When I encounter a non built-in command I fork a new process and overlay a new image with the provided arguments. The general format is command arg1 arg2 ... argn < infile > outfile. So the args (arg1 to argn) would be passed in the new image and the input and outputs would be changed to infile and outfile Here is a snippet of what my forking process looks like.

```
pid = fork();

if (pid < 0) {
   fprintf(stderr, "*** fork error ***\n");
} else if (pid == 0) {
   execvp(command, args);
}

waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
```

Is there a unix command that will allow me to do this? I was also thinking that there might be a way to change stdin and stdout in the new image? Any links or info would be appreciated.

Comment: "fork error" is not a useful message.  Please use perror().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Unix, you generally want `dup2` for this. See [libc docs](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Duplicating-Descriptors.html) for duplicating file descriptors.

Answer (score 2):

In the forked process, just before `exec`-ing the new image, close file handles 0 (stdin), 1 (stdout) and possibly 2 (stderr).

Then use `open()` to open the necessary files in the correct order (stdin, out, and err). They will each use the first entries in the file handles table - 0, 1 and 2. So the first file you open will be treated as `stdin` from now on.